# Show labels inside each bubble in dimplejs bubble chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, dimple.js

I am making a bubble chart using dimplejs. That part is done. I also want to add the owner name (bubble label) inside the bubble and not just as a list outside the chart but this is not working. How should I go ahead?

[Link to the jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/acjwqpsL/).

```
all_data = [{"Size": 126, "x": 0.57713748637776141, "y": -0.23994977513487858, "Owner": "a"}, {"Size": 394, "x": -0.23305704511539499, "y": -0.39183313136189662, "Owner": "b"}, {"Size": 127, "x": 0.12093459993205866, "y": 0.56390700220806189, "Owner": "c"}, {"Size": 624, "x": -0.46501504119442505, "y": 0.06787590428871329, "Owner": "d"}] 

var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 600, 200);

var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, all_data);
myChart.setBounds(25, 25, 550, 150)

var x = myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "x");
var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "y");
x.hidden = true;
y.hidden = true;

myChart.addLegend(25, 5, 550, 20, "right");
myChart.addMeasureAxis("z", "Size");

var s = myChart.addSeries("Owner", dimple.plot.bubble);

myChart.draw();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your JSFiddle, there was a commented block which was close to the right answer, however you missed a couple of things.  Firstly circles use the cx and cy properties rather than x and y so you need to refer to those for position.  Secondly you were calling s.shapes.each before the draw method and the shapes property of the series is only populated after drawing.  You could move the block after the draw method, but I have switched it to use the series.afterDraw property instead:

```
s.afterDraw = function (shp, d) {
    var shape = d3.select(shp);
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", parseFloat(shape.attr("cx")))
        .attr("y", parseFloat(shape.attr("cy")) + 4)
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("font-size", "10px")
        .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .style("opacity", 0.7)
        .text(d.zValue);
};
```

Your updated fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/acjwqpsL/2/

Comment: Note, this answer requires you to upgrade to dimple.js [version 2+](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/releases)

Comment: Also, here's a [quick update](http://jsfiddle.net/acjwqpsL/3/) to show "owner" in the bubble instead of "size".

Comment: Thanks John and Mark! One more thing, how do I find the radius of the bubble since I would like to put the text outside the bubble in case the bubble is smaller than the text...